# Java script error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

[image: This is the error shown when I click on javascript button]

Code which is working

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}
window.open('/apex/transferrequest?id={!Case.Id}');
```

Code which is not working

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}
if({!Case.Status}  =  'Closed'){
    alert('Case is Closed cannot update.');
}
else{
    window.open('/apex/TransferRequest?id={!Case.Id}')
}
```

If statement is being validated alert is shown, but there is some issue with else. What could be the possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any programming language:

1. `=` means **Assignment**
2. `==` means **Comparison**

Also JavaScript is [Dynamically typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964910/is-javascript-an-untyped-language) programming languages, so you have to be careful while comparison. Status should be in quotes!

So, try changing:

```
if({!Case.Status}  =  'Closed')
```

to:

```
if("{!Case.Status}" == "Closed")
```